# solve_ivp returning different outcome of odeint?

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am trying to solve a simple ODE so as to understand the new API of Scipy.

I wrote a routine for Runge Kutta of order 4 to write it and confirmed it with the old API odeint and it matched beautifully. But now that I am trying to get around the solve_ivp, it seems that is not working. What am I getting wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp, odeint
import time

freq = np.arange(1, 10000, 100)

def g(q, t):
    return -q ** 3 + np.sin(t)


a = 0
b = 10
npoints = 100
h = (b - a) / npoints
t = np.arange(a, b, h)

output1 = np.zeros(t.shape)
x = 0
for i in range(len(t)):
    output1[i] = x
    k1 = h * g(x, t[i])
    k2 = h * g(x + 0.5 * k1, t[i] + 0.5 * h)
    k3 = h * g(x + 0.5 * k2, t[i] + 0.5 * h)
    k4 = h * g(x + k3, t[i] + 0.5 * h)
    x = x + 1 / 6 * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4)


# ---------------Solving using odeint (old API)---------------#

y1_odeint = odeint(g, 0, t)

#---------------Solving using new API-------------#

y2=solve_ivp(g,(a,b),[0],t_eval=t)


# --------------------Representação gráfica--------------------------#
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(122)

ax.plot(t, output1,label="my own")
ax.plot(t,y1_odeint,label="odeint")
ax.plot(y2.t,np.squeeze(y2.y),label="new API")
ax.legend()
ax.set_title("Output")

ax1.plot(t,output1-np.squeeze(y1_odeint),label="|odeint-my own|")
ax1.legend()


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take another look at the docstring for [`solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html).  It expects the *first* argument of `g` to be `t`.  By default, [`odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) uses the opposite convention.  If you have a recent version of scipy, you can tell `odeint` that the first argument is `t` by giving it the argument `tfirst=True`.